# Как использовать именованные функциональные выражения в классе javascript?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Прошу помощи в следующем вопросе.
Допустим у меня есть некоторое именованное функциональное выражение, как мне эту функцию сделать методом класса, используя es6?
Например, для простоты я хочу, чтобы у меня функция нахождения степени:

```
let exponentiation = function pow(x, n) {
    let result = x;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
};
```

стала методом класса NewClass, используя es6:

```
class NewClass {
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

чтобы потом можно было вызвать вот так:

```
newClass.exponentiation(2, 3);
```

Или может нет смысла использовать именованные функциональные выражения вообще в в качестве методов класса?
Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Запихните просто функцию в объявление класса и все

```
class NewClass {
  constructor(){
  }

  exponentiation(x, n) {
    let result = x;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
  };
}
```

Или вот так

```
let exponentiation = function pow(x, n) {
    let result = x;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
};

class NewClass {
    constructor(){
    }
}
NewClass.prototype.exponentiation = exponentiation
```

Хотя в данном случае в функции нет обращения к контексту, поэтому можно ее статической сделать

```
let exponentiation = function pow(x, n) {
    let result = x;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
};

class NewClass {
    constructor(){
    }
}
NewClass.exponentiation = exponentiation
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете при создании класса, создавать методы с помощью обьекта "this"

```
class NewClass {
  constructor(){
    this.exponentiation = exponentiation;
  }
}
```

и после сможете спокойно их вызывать:

```
let newClass = new NewClass();
newClass.exponentiation(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let exponentiation = function pow(x, n) {
    let result = x;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }

    return result;
};

class NewClass {
    constructor(){
    }
}

var a = new NewClass();
a.x = 1;
a.n = 2;
a.exponentiation = exponentiation;
console.log(a.exponentiation(a.x, a.n));
```